# Django: Linking two tables

Tags: python, sql, django, database

first of all, I'm aware that this question might've been answered already, but there are two reasons why I'm opening another question: One, obviously, is I'm struggling with the Django syntax. Secondly, and perhaps more importantly, I'm not quite sure whether my database setup makes even sense at this point. So, please bear with me.

I work in a hospital and one of my daily stuggles is that, oftentimes, one single drug can have a lot of different names. So, I thought that'd be a good task to practice some Django with.

Basically I want two databases: One that simply links the drugs "nick name" to it's actual name. And another one which links the actual name to some additional information, something along the lines of a wiki page.

What I've come up with so far:

```
(django)django@ip:~/medwiki$ cat medsearch/models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class medsearch(models.Model):
    proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
    non_proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.non_proprietary_name

class medwiki(models.Model):
    proprietary_name = models.ForeignKey('medisearch', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cetegory = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    #wiki = models.TextField() etc. 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.proprietary_name
(django)django@ip-:~/medwiki$
```

So, I can add a new "medsearch object" just fine. However, when adding the "Category" at medwiki I get `__str__ returned non-string (type medsearch)`. Presumably, because there's more than one key in medsearch? I thus suspect that "FroeignKey" is not suited for this application and I know that there are other ways to link databases in Django. However, I don't know which one to choose and how to implement it correctly.

Hopefully, some of you have some ideas?

EDIT: Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
class Proprietary_name(models.Model):
    proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.proprietary_name

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Mediwiki(models.Model):
    proprietary_name = models.ManyToManyField(Proprietary_name)
    non_proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    wiki_page = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.non_proprietary_name
```

Now I can attribute different categorys and different proprietary_names to one drug. Which works great so far.

So does looking up the non-proprietary_name when I know the proprietary "nick name".

```
>>> Mediwiki.objects.get(proprietary_name__proprietary_name="Aspirin")
<Mediwiki: acetylsalicylic acid>
>>>
```

However, I'd also like to display all the proprietary_names, when I know the non_proprietary_name. Do I have to further change the database design, or am I just missing some other thing here?

Comment: "one single drug can have a lot of different names" In you example, which table has the main name and which one has the other names.

Comment: Your question about `__str__` was answered thoroughly in the answers, but your database design has serious problems. First of them - you store proprietary name along with non-proprietary (generic) one; as one generic can have many proprietary names, that would mean you'd store the same name in many places, unnecessarily taking space and making it a nightmare if you ever need to correct it. The topic of proper DB design is too broad for a comment or even an answer, I'd recommend  reading a book about relational database design first.

Comment: @François The main name would be the "non_proprietary_name". The nick names would be the "proprietary_name"(s).

Comment: @rafalmp Okay, I'm definetly convinced now that my database design is quite poor. However, reading an entire book on that subject is, sadly, out of question for the moment. I'm guessing it's not the most difficult database setup, mind giving me a little hand?

Comment: @theCed7 - in that case you want one table for the non_proprietary name and the wiki together and one table of nick names (with the foreign key in it).

Comment: as @François wrote, then I'd move `category` to another table with ManyToMany relationship to generic drug table (as a drug can fall into many categories, even simple Aspirin falls into Antiplatelet Agents, Cardiovascular; Antiplatelet Agents, Hematologic; NSAIDs; Salicylates - and obviously there is a lot of drugs in a category), then I'd need to know exactly what information are you planning to store to help...

Comment: @rafalmp Exactly, adding more than one category would also be quite handy. Mind having a look at my edit? Is that roughly what you had in mind?

Comment: OK, but the answers below solve one of your problems - why `__str__` doesn't work. Your database structure is quite a different problem, so please move it to a new question and I'll try to help you with that.

Comment: @rafalmp Yes, you're probably right. I've opend a new question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
return self.proprietary_name.proprietary_name
```

But that doesn't really make sense !

---

The main issue is that you've called the foreign key to `medsearch`, `proprietary_name`.

The second issue is just a convention one. In Python (and many programming languages), classes must start with an uppercase letter.

The following would be better:

```
class MedSearch(models.Model):
    proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    non_proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.non_proprietary_name

class MedWiki(models.Model):
    med_search = models.ForeignKey('MedSearch', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='wikis')
    cetegory = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    #wiki = models.TextField() etc. 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.med_serach.proprietary_name
```

Answer (score 1):

As you note, the `proprietary_name` field on medwiki is a ForeignKey. You can't return that value directly from the `__str__` method because that needs to return a string. You need to convert that value into a string before returning it: either use the default string representation of the medsearch instance:

```
return str(self.proprietary_name)
```

or choose a specific string field to return:

```
return self.proprietary_name.proprietary_name
```